# SQL select rows with unique values

Tags: sql

I'm having a problem getting the rows I need from my database.

The question is simple: I have a table with customer data in it.
Now I want to do a mailing (via post) to all my customers, but I only want to send it to every address once. So if any customers live on the same address (street, number, postal code, city) I only want to send the letter to the oldest person living at that address.

The fields I need are title, last name, first name, street, number, ... (for exporting purposes). I tried using group by on the address fields but then I get the error I need to use an aggregate function on the other fields (name, ...) and I don't want to do that...

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should post some sample data from your table and the query that you tried to write yourself.

Comment: Also, how do you determine the oldest person from that address?

Comment: How is possible that two people live in the same address? If they are family, obviously... But in that case you can send the message to that persons to the same address. By the way, if you have two different person with the same address after an update; I think that you have anomalies actualizations. If so, you will have to normalize your relations.

Comment: The oldest person is the person with the first birth date. And it is perfectly possible that familymembers live at the same address. To spare costs I want to send only 1 letter to that address, to the oldest person. I have no anomalies in my data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT title
     , last_name
     , first_name
     , address_line_1
     , address_line_2
     , etc
FROM   (
        SELECT title
             , last_name
             , first_name
             , address_line_1
             , address_line_2
             , etc
             , Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY address_line_1, address_line_2, etc ORDER BY date_of_birth ASC) As row_number
        FROM   your_table
       ) As all_duplicatified
WHERE  row_num = 1
```

This gives every row a row number. The row number is "reset" on every partition (which in this case is our address fields) and the ordering of the numbers is determined by age (dob).

Therefore if we only show the ones where `row_num = 1` we get just that eldest persons entry first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this really was the solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can you the following SQL construct:

```
select distinct ...
```

Select distinct will avoid duplicates in your result set. You can use select distinct to gather all unique addresses and then cross reference with the email address

Answer (score 0):

Use [SELECT DISTINCT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187831%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to only select unique adresses

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do something like this in Oracle:

```
--Create testing table
CREATE TABLE UniqueValTest (
  fname NVARCHAR2(100),
  lname NVARCHAR2(100),
  address NVARCHAR2(100),
  city NVARCHAR2(50),
  state NVARCHAR2(2),
  zip NVARCHAR2(5),
  age NUMBER,
  recid NUMBER
  );

--Create sample data
INSERT INTO UniqueValTest (fname, lname, address, city, state, zip, age, recid)
VALUES ('JOHN', 'SMITH', '123 MAIN ST', 'JAMESTOWN', 'LA', '12345', 28, 1);
INSERT INTO UniqueValTest (fname, lname, address, city, state, zip, age, recid)
VALUES ('JENNIFER', 'SMITH', '123 MAIN ST', 'JAMESTOWN', 'LA', '12345', 30, 2);
INSERT INTO UniqueValTest (fname, lname, address, city, state, zip, age, recid)
VALUES ('RACHEL', 'ALLEN', '225 MAIN ST', 'JAMESTOWN', 'LA', '12345', 25, 3);
INSERT INTO UniqueValTest (fname, lname, address, city, state, zip, age, recid)
VALUES ('JOSEPH', 'ALLEN', '225 MAIN ST', 'JAMESTOWN', 'LA', '12345', 25, 4);
INSERT INTO UniqueValTest (fname, lname, address, city, state, zip, age, recid)
VALUES ('MARK', 'MCBRIDE', '228 MAIN ST', 'JAMESTOWN', 'LA', '12345', 55, 5);

--Here's the real part, pulling the data with the dedupe and priority
CREATE TABLE TestDataPull AS
  SELECT T.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY lname, address, zip ORDER BY lname, address, zip, age DESC NULLS LAST) AS dupeid
  FROM UNIQUEVALTEST T;

--Now you can easily select your data
SELECT fname, lname, address, city, state, zip FROM TestDataPull WHERE dupeid = 1;
```