# Select Rows with unique column value in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've done a lot of searching and I feel like this should be an easy solution but I can't get anything to work.

I have a database table that holds a nested array. After I unnest the array and select just the columns I want, I end up with a table that looks like this:

```
SELECT time_period, name, value
FROM 
    TBL.TBLValues,
    UNNEST(nested_name) as unnested_name
WHERE time_period > '2021-07-01 00:00:00'
AND name != "None"
ORDER BY time_period;
```

| row | time_period | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-07-01T00:00:00 | Name1 | 100 |
| 2 | 2021-07-01T00:00:00 | Name2 | 105 |
| 3 | 2021-07-01T00:05:00 | Name1 | 120 |
| 4 | 2021-07-01T00:10:00 | Name3 | 500 |
| 5 | 2021-07-01T00:15:00 | Name1 | 110 |
| 6 | 2021-07-01T00:15:00 | Name3 | 450 |
| 7 | 2021-07-01T00:20:00 | Name1 | 1000 |

What I want to do is filter my query (probably through a nested query?) so I only get rows where `time_period` is unique. In the table above, I would only return rows 3 and 4, as all other rows have multiple names for the same time_period.

I tried `SELECT DISTINCT(period)` and that is  filtering it down substantially as far as the number of returned rows is concerned, but it is definitely returning rows that have multiple names for the same `time_period`. I'm not sure why, my understanding of that function is that it should only return rows where `time_period` exists exactly once.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(time_period)
        FROM
        TBL.TBLValues,
        UNNEST(nested_name) as unnested_name
        WHERE time_period > '2021-07-01 00:00:00'
        AND name != 'None'
    ORDER BY period;
```

I also tried a `COUNT(time_period) AS counter` and then a `HAVING counter = 1` at the end of my query. This came closest to what I want I think, it's returning very few results, I think the `GROUP BY` may have been doing something weird? It only gives me one `time_period` per name, but some of those `time_period`s are duplicates. Also ideally the next step in this filter is to take every unique `time_period`, then filter to the most recent `time_period` for each unique `Name`, so it would be nice to get this to initially return every unique `time_period` so I could do that next.

```
SELECT COUNT(time_period) as counter, time_period, name, value
FROM(
    SELECT time_period, name, value
    FROM  TBL.TBLValues,
            UNNEST(nested_name) as unnested_name
            WHERE time_period > '2021-07-01 00:00:00'
            AND name != 'None')
GROUP BY name, value, time_period
HAVING counter = 1
ORDER BY time_period;
```

I also tried reworking the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852722/sql-select-rows-with-unique-values) with the `PARTITION BY` but wasn't able to get it to filter my results at all.

```
SELECT time_period, name, value
FROM(
    SELECT time_period, name, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY time_period ORDER BY value ASC) AS row_num
    FROM  TBL.TBLValues,
            UNNEST(nested_name) as unested_name
            WHERE time_period > '2021-07-01 00:00:00'
            AND name != 'None') as all_duplicated
WHERE row_num = 1
ORDER BY time_period;
```

Comment: Add tag for database platform. And no, that is not what DISTINCT is intended to accomplish. It forces retrieving only one copy of unique data, whether duplicate rows or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.  Here's one (with standard SQL):

```
WITH xrows AS (
       SELECT tbl.*
            , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY time_period) AS n
         FROM tbl
     )
SELECT *
  FROM xrows
 WHERE n = 1
 ORDER BY time_period
;
```

and with your SQL as a starting point:

```
WITH your_sql AS (
        SELECT time_period, name, value
             , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY time_period) AS n
          FROM TBL.TBLValues,
            UNNEST(nested_name) as unnested_name
         WHERE time_period > '2021-07-01 00:00:00'
           AND name != 'None'
     )
SELECT *
  FROM your_sql
 WHERE n = 1
 ORDER BY time_period
;
```

and now with the given available data:

```
WITH your_sql (row, time_period, name, value) AS (
        SELECT 1, '2021-07-01T00:00:00', 'Name1', 100 UNION ALL
        SELECT 2, '2021-07-01T00:00:00', 'Name2', 105 UNION ALL
        SELECT 3, '2021-07-01T00:05:00', 'Name1', 120 UNION ALL
        SELECT 4, '2021-07-01T00:10:00', 'Name3', 500 UNION ALL
        SELECT 5, '2021-07-01T00:15:00', 'Name1', 110 UNION ALL
        SELECT 6, '2021-07-01T00:15:00', 'Name3', 450
     )
   , xrows AS (
          SELECT t.*
               , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY time_period) AS n
            FROM your_sql AS t
     )
SELECT * FROM xrows WHERE n = 1
 ORDER BY time_period
;
```

Result:

```
+-----+---------------------+-------+-------+---+
| row | time_period         | name  | value | n |
+-----+---------------------+-------+-------+---+
|   3 | 2021-07-01T00:05:00 | Name1 |   120 | 1 |
|   4 | 2021-07-01T00:10:00 | Name3 |   500 | 1 |
+-----+---------------------+-------+-------+---+
```

Here's the updated solution for the new requirement.  I've added a duplicate row for row=3 (row=7), but only one of the rows will be shown.  This case would have been removed in the previous COUNT logic:

```
WITH your_sql (row, time_period, name, value) AS (
        SELECT 1, '2021-07-01T00:00:00', 'Name1', 100 UNION ALL
        SELECT 2, '2021-07-01T00:00:00', 'Name2', 105 UNION ALL
        SELECT 3, '2021-07-01T00:05:00', 'Name1', 120 UNION ALL
        SELECT 7, '2021-07-01T00:05:00', 'Name1', 120 UNION ALL
        SELECT 4, '2021-07-01T00:10:00', 'Name3', 500 UNION ALL
        SELECT 5, '2021-07-01T00:15:00', 'Name1', 110 UNION ALL
        SELECT 6, '2021-07-01T00:15:00', 'Name3', 450
     )
   , xrows0 AS (
          SELECT t.*
               , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY time_period ORDER BY name, value, row) AS n1
               , RANK()       OVER (PARTITION BY time_period ORDER BY name, value     ) AS n2
            FROM your_sql AS t
     )
   , xrows AS (
          SELECT t.*
               , MAX(n2) OVER (PARTITION BY time_period) AS m2
            FROM xrows0 AS t
     )
SELECT *
  FROM xrows
 WHERE m2 = 1
   AND n1 = 1
 ORDER BY time_period
;

Result:
+-----+---------------------+-------+-------+----+----+------+
| row | time_period         | name  | value | n1 | n2 | m2   |
+-----+---------------------+-------+-------+----+----+------+
|   3 | 2021-07-01T00:05:00 | Name1 |   120 |  1 |  1 |    1 |
|   4 | 2021-07-01T00:10:00 | Name3 |   500 |  1 |  1 |    1 |
+-----+---------------------+-------+-------+----+----+------+
```

and the new requirement, where only the name needs to be the same over that time_period, and with your new data row:

```
WITH your_sql (row, time_period, name, value) AS (
        SELECT 1, '2021-07-01T00:00:00', 'Name1',  100 UNION ALL
        SELECT 2, '2021-07-01T00:00:00', 'Name2',  105 UNION ALL
        SELECT 3, '2021-07-01T00:05:00', 'Name1',  120 UNION ALL
        SELECT 8, '2021-07-01T00:05:00', 'Name1',  120 UNION ALL
        SELECT 4, '2021-07-01T00:10:00', 'Name3',  500 UNION ALL
        SELECT 5, '2021-07-01T00:15:00', 'Name1',  110 UNION ALL
        SELECT 6, '2021-07-01T00:15:00', 'Name3',  450 UNION ALL
        SELECT 7, '2021-07-01T00:20:00', 'Name1', 1000
     )
   , xrows0 AS (
          SELECT t.*
               , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY time_period ORDER BY name, row  ) AS n1
               , RANK()       OVER (PARTITION BY time_period ORDER BY name, value) AS n2
            FROM your_sql AS t
     )
   , xrows AS (
          SELECT t.*
               , MAX(n2) OVER (PARTITION BY time_period) AS m2
            FROM xrows0 AS t
     )
SELECT *
  FROM xrows
 WHERE m2 = 1
   AND n1 = 1
 ORDER BY time_period
;

+-----+---------------------+-------+-------+----+----+------+
| row | time_period         | name  | value | n1 | n2 | m2   |
+-----+---------------------+-------+-------+----+----+------+
|   3 | 2021-07-01T00:05:00 | Name1 |   120 |  1 |  1 |    1 |
|   4 | 2021-07-01T00:10:00 | Name3 |   500 |  1 |  1 |    1 |
|   7 | 2021-07-01T00:20:00 | Name1 |  1000 |  1 |  1 |    1 |
+-----+---------------------+-------+-------+----+----+------+
```

Comment: This is still returning a much smaller number of results than I'm expecting

Comment: Provide a test case (with INSERT statements) that leads to the behavior you don't understand.  We can then review together.  Note: This was easily tested.  I just don't have your data, which shouldn't really change the behavior.

Comment: Your note about ```as all other rows have multiple names for the same time_period``` might be a hint.  Did you really care whether the names were different or just that there was only one row in the result with each time_period?  If you meant something else, the logic may need to change slightly.  Remember, your initial requirement was only that ```time_period``` is unique in the result.

Comment: Perhaps a better way to explain- This dataset updated every 5 min with None or The Name and Value of objects of interest. I am trying to extract every period that has exactly 1 Name/Value pair associated with it. That would give me a list with many duplicate Names. I would then wish to filter that list down to simply the most recent entry for each unique name. Its a large dataset and I'm not entirely sure whats going wrong, only that I'm getting fewer results than I know I should.

Comment: Do you mind adding that data to your test case in the question?  I think you want to add a case where the time_period is seen more than once, but the name/value pair is the same also.  That case would not be shown in the current result with just the COUNT window function and only a time_period partition.  That sounds like the issue.  Adjust your requirement to reflect this as well.

Comment: Also, for these cases where the time_period, name and value are the same for 1 or more rows, do you just want one instance of that case in the result?

Comment: I added a row 7 to the example. In the new example I would keep Rows 3,4,7. That would give me two rows with Name1, but every instance where there is only one Name per time_period. After I've done that across all 100k rows, I want to filter to the most recent time_period for each Name. So the end result would be to keep only rows 4 and 7 (7 being the most recent interval with Name1).

Comment: Ok.  But you previously said "has exactly 1 Name/Value pair".  Do you only care that the name is the same within the same time_period?  The 7th row you added has a completely new time_period and every one of my examples would have allowed that one into the result.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is probably `qualify`

```
SELECT time_period, name, value
FROM TBL.TBLValues t CROSS JOIN
     UNNEST(t.nested_name) as unnested_name
WHERE time_period > '2021-07-01 00:00:00' AND
      name <> 'None'
QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY time_period) = 1
ORDER BY time_period;
```

Comment: This gives me an error "Name time_period not found inside t"

Comment: @ghw29 . . . Then remove the `t.`.  Your question doesn't show the layout of the table, so I guess I assumed it was in `tblValues` and not `unnested_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
select * from (
  select * from (
    SELECT time_period, name, value
    FROM TBL.TBLValues,
      UNNEST(nested_name) as unnested_name
    WHERE time_period > '2021-07-01 00:00:00'
    AND name != "None"
  )
  where true
  qualify count(*) over(partition by time_period) = 1
)
where true
qualify row_number() over(partition by name order by time_period desc) = 1
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]